# param is missing or the value is empty: user - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got the following rails app, which allows users to subscribe to widgets. i.e. Many-to-Many through model with Users-to-Widgets through Subscriptions.

My Models:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :widget
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :widget_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :widgets, through: :subscriptions
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end
```

My Controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController
  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update(user_subscription_params)
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Subscriptions updated"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def user_subscription_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:widget_ids)
  end
end
```

and this is being rendered in `views/subscriptions/_forms.html.erb` like this:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_subscription_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :widget_ids, Widget.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting the error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"subscriptions"} missing required keys: [:id]

I would be really grateful of any ideas how to fix this.

Edit:

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  resources :widgets
    resources :subscriptions
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do  
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'     
  end

authenticated :user do
  root to: 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
end
```

Comment: can you post your routes file

Comment: @chaitanya Sure, please see the question update

Comment: also method :put would be used instead of :patch

Comment: @chaitanya Sorry, I dont know what you mean?

Comment: try this <%= form_for @user, url: subscription_path(@user.id), method: :put do |f| %>

Comment: @chaitanya Thanks, that seems to have helped, but I am now getting the error `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105142/discussion-between-chaitanya-and-george-edwards).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_subscription_path(@user), method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :widget_ids, Widget.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```